# Displaying error messages from catch statements with toast

Tags: java, android

I have the following catch statement in my Android application and I would like to display any error messages via toast, can I do that?

```
catch (Exception e) 
{
    //Helper.displayExceptionMessage(this, e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

```
public static void displayExceptionMessage(Context context, String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(context, msg , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I’ve also tried to make a helper class to display the message but I have no idea how to resolve "Helper".

Comment: What do you mean by "resolve helper"? What's the question?

Comment: Instead of error, try, e.getMessage()

Comment: ^this will give the Exception object's toString, which probably contains the error

Answer (score 8):

Thanks guys,

e.getMessage() did the trick,

I did it like this,

```
{
    ...    
    catch (Exception e) 
    {       
        e.printStackTrace();
        displayExceptionMessage(e.getMessage());
    }       
} 

public void displayExceptionMessage(String msg)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

That way I can use it for testing throughout the whole activity I Guess. I don't know it could be overkill!!!

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

`catch (System.Exception e){`

```
           // log the error to the android logs.
            Android.Util.Log.D("MEDIA_PLAYER", e.Message);
            Toast.MakeText(this, e.Message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).Show();
        }
```

Comment: ToastLength.Short or Toast.LENGTH_SHORT?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like This,

```
catch (Exception e)
        { 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is working for me if you want a custom error hope will be helpful:

```
 getActivity().runOnUiThread(Runnable { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
```