# No data inserted to MySQL from Android

Tags: php, android, mysql, sqlite

In my app, I need the data insert to two places when register button is clicked, one is to `SQLite` and another is to `MySQL` (Xampp server). Data are successfully added into `SQLite` but no luck with `MySQL`.

**Register**

```
 private static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.107.115/Android/CRUD/register.php";

     register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Password=password.getText().toString();
                   ConfirmPassword=confirmPassword.getText().toString();
                        sqlcon.open();
                        sqlcon.insertEntry(deviceName, Password); // insert to SQLite, no problem
                        register(deviceName, Password); // insert to MySQL

                    }

                }
            });    
        }

        private void register(String name,String password) {
            class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
                ProgressDialog loading;
                RequestHandler ruc = new RequestHandler();


                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    loading = ProgressDialog.show(Register.this, "Please Wait",null, true, true);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                    super.onPostExecute(s);
                    loading.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"AA"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    data.put("name",params[0]);
                    data.put("password",params[1]);
                    String result = ruc.sendPostRequest(REGISTER_URL,data);
                    return  result;
                }
            }

            RegisterUser ru = new RegisterUser();
            ru.execute(name,password);
        }
```

**RequestHandler**

```
public class RequestHandler {

        public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                      HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

            URL url;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try {
                //Initializing Url
                url = new URL(requestURL);

                //Creating an httmlurl connection
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                //Configuring connection properties
                conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
                conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);

                //Creating an output stream
                OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();

                //Writing parameters to the request
                //We are using a method getPostDataString which is defined below
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
                writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();
                int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String response;
                    //Reading server response
                    while ((response = br.readLine()) != null){
                        sb.append(response);
                    }
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String sendGetRequest(String requestURL){
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestURL);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String s;
                while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(s+"\n");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        public String sendGetRequestParam(String requestURL, String id){
            StringBuilder sb =new StringBuilder();
            try {
                URL url = new URL(requestURL+id);
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                String s;
                while((s=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                    sb.append(s+"\n");
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }

        private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            boolean first = true;
            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
                if (first)
                    first = false;
                else
                    result.append("&");

                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
                result.append("=");
                result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
            }

            return result.toString();
        }
    }
```

When register button is clicked, I saw the `Toast` message displayed which is inside the **Register** `onPostExecute`.

In **RequestHandler**, `sendGetRequest`,`sendGetRequestParam` is **never used** ! When check in MySQL, no data is inserted.

Comment: The progressDialog  just shows not even 1 sec then display Toast.

Comment: Since I see `0` php & MySQL code, I assume that you have determined that it is not a php/MySQL issue. So why did you tag php & MySQL?

Comment: Most/All of the methods you use in sendPostRequest() have a return value. Check each and every of them for error conditions. Also add an `else`-branch for `if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK)`. Log any condition that indicates that something went wrong and/or do something "in" the UI to make the error condition visible.

Comment: @VolkerK Thanks for your response. When register button is clicked, the progress dialog shows not even 1 sec, then it display the Toast in `onPostExecute`. Is there a way I can check where are the error came from?

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8016967/displaying-error-messages-from-catch-statements-with-toast ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solved after I open the wifi-connection in my real device. What a incredibly stupid  mistakes I made :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you choose this kind of architect. this is highly insecure because if anyone decompile your code they can find your online database password and access to all of your data easily and even  worse delete everything. this is why words like `API` born. you should create a page in the server side which accepts a `POST` request and validate the variables. then add it to online database and return for example a Json string confirming the insert.

Comment: Where's the "online database password" in that code?

Comment: I follow [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql/). The difference is I have included the `SQLite`